# Debian with SLAAC does not get DNS via DHCPv6

Tags: debian, ipv6, isc-dhcpd

I have two Debian Bullseye containers, one acting as a router. The client gets the router advertisement ant autocinfigures its IPv6 address correctly but it doesn't set the DNS server addresses that it should be getting via DHCPv6.

I've tried doing the same in other environments and machines, even with *only* IPv6 and it's always the same. I'm quite stumped and don't know what else to do. Is there something I'm missing?

**ROUTER**

- Interface configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
    auto eth1
    iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.11.1/24
    iface eth1 inet6 static
        address a:b:c:11::1/64
    iface eth1 inet6 static
        address fe80::1/64
```

- Subnet section of the `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd6.conf` file for `isc-dhcp-server.service`:

```
    subnet6 a:b:c:11::/64 {
        option dhcp6.name-servers 2001:4860:4860::8888, 2001:4860:4860::8844;
    }
```

- Contents of `/etc/radvd.conf` file:

```
    interface eth1 {
        AdvSendAdvert on;
        AdvOtherConfigFlag on;
    
        prefix a:b:c:11::/64 {};
    
    #   route a:b:c:11::/64 {};
    };
```

**CLIENT**

- Contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
    auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet dhcp
    iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

- Router Advertisement captured with `radvdump`:

```
    #
    # radvd configuration generated by radvdump 2.18
    # based on Router Advertisement from fe80::1
    # received by interface eth0
    #
    
    interface eth0
    {
        AdvSendAdvert on;
        # Note: {Min,Max}RtrAdvInterval cannot be obtained with radvdump
        AdvManagedFlag off;
        AdvOtherConfigFlag on;
        AdvReachableTime 0;
        AdvRetransTimer 0;
        AdvCurHopLimit 64;
        AdvDefaultLifetime 1800;
        AdvHomeAgentFlag off;
        AdvDefaultPreference medium;
        AdvSourceLLAddress on;
    
        prefix a:b:c:11::/64
        {
            AdvValidLifetime 86400;
            AdvPreferredLifetime 14400;
            AdvOnLink on;
            AdvAutonomous on;
            AdvRouterAddr off;
        }; # End of prefix definition
    
    }; # End of interface definition
```

Comment: Add a line `dhcp 1` after `iface eth0 inet6 auto` in `/etc/network/interfaces` on the client. This gets additional config from DHCP

Comment: It works, but this line forces the client to get the DNS server addresses via DHCP. What I'd really want is that it did so simply by receiving the "other configuration flag" from the RA.